# Awesome font is not working on ionic angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

Am trying to use Awesome font in my ionic 5 project I have successfully implemented it, if I use if in the html file it works fine but I want to replace it a button text when clicked with a spinner.

**My html code**

```
<button ion-button type="submit" (click)="submitt()" class="btn-Yellow [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" [innerHTML]="btnText | safe: 'html'">
</button>
```

**TS code**

```
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  btnText: string;

  constructor() {
    this.btnText = '<span style="color:white">Login</span>';
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  submitt(): void {
    this.btnText = '<fa-icon icon="spinner"></fa-icon>';
  }
}
```

I really need your help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fa-icon` is a component. You can't make Angular component working(unless it's a web component) with `innerHTML`. Angular won't compile it at all.

The easiest way to solve your problem is to threw away innerHTML and use regular html instead with the help of some flag.

**html**

```
<button ion-button type="submit" (click)="submitt()" class="btn-Yellow [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
   <span *ngIf="!loading" style="color:white">Login</span>
   <fa-icon *ngIf="loading" icon="spinner"></fa-icon>
</button>
```

ts

```
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  loading = false;

  submitt(): void {
    this.loading = true;
  }
}
```

Another way to add icon dynamically is to use progammatic API provided by Angular Awesome library https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/usage/features.md#programmatic-api But I don't think you want to dig into it:)

Comment: You are the angel God sent to me.... it worked like charm... :(